# How can I add a page at image size?

Tags: size, page

I'm wiritng a document with A4 pages to which I must add some images as "attachments" of different sizes. I'd like to have each "attachment" in a standalone page the same size of the image. For example:

1. 100 "normal" pages (A4 = 210x297 mm), followed by
2. a B7 page (125x88 mm) with a passport cover scan, followed by
3. a 300x500 mm page with a map

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to automatically put each image on its own page with exactly the same size (without margins)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package [`incgraph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) is designed for tasks like this.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}
first page

% this creates the second page, with page size the same as size of figure example-iamge
\incmultigraph{example-image}{1}

third page
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but I have problems with my `twocolumn` document. I have to give an explicit `\clearpage` before each image or a `\onecolumn` before the serie (and `\twocolumn` after to restore the original layout) in order to avoid them overlapping each other and the text in the same page where `\incgraph` is used. Is there a way to fx that? I couldn't find anything in `incgraph` manual.

Comment: @Ntakwetet I'm afraid there is no easy fixing.